# What's the most efficient way to extract data in this case?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

So, I'm working on a python web application, it's a search engine for sporting goods (sport outfits, tools ....etc) . Basically it should search for a given keyword on multiple stores and compare results to return the 20 best results .

I was thinking that the best and easiest way to do this is to write a json file wich contains rules for the scraper on how to extract data on each website . For ex:

```
[{"www.decathlon.com" : { "rules" : { "productTag" : "div['.product']", 
"priceTag" : "span[".price"]" } }]
```

So for decathlon, to get product item we search for div tags with the product class .

I have a list of around 10 - 15 websites to scrape . So for each website it goes to rules.json, see the related rules and use them to extract data .

**Pros for this Method** : 
Very Easy to write, we need a minimal python script for the logic on how to read and map urls to their rules and extract the data through BeautifulSoup  + It's also very easy to add, delete new urls and their rules .

**Cons of this method** : For each search we launch a request to each website, so making around 10 requests at the same time, then compare results, so if 20 users search at the same time we will have around 200 requests which will slow down our app a lot !

**Another Method :**

I thought that we could have a huge list of keywords, then at 00:00, a script launch requests to all the urls for each keyword in the list, compare them, then store the results in CouchDB, to be used through the day, and It will be updated daily . The only problem with this method is that it's nearly impossible to have a list of all possible keywords .

So please, help me on how should I proceed with this ? Given that I don't have a lot of time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of your "keyword" list: rather than keeping a list of all possible keywords, perhaps you could maintain a priority queue of keywords with importance based on how often a keyword is searched. When a new keyword is encountered, add it to the list, otherwise update it's importance every time it's searched. Launch a script to request urls for the top, say, 30 keywords each day (more or less depending on how often words are searched and what you want to do).

This doesn't necessarily solve your problem of having too many requests, but may decrease the likelihood of it becoming too much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP requests can be very expensive. That's why you want to make sure you parallelize your requests and for that you can use something like Celery. This way you will reduce total time to the time of slowest responding website. 
It may be a good idea to set request timeout to shorter time (5 seconds?) in case one of the website is not responding to your request. 
Have the ability to flag domain as "down/not responding" and be able to handle those exceptions.

Other optimization would be to store page contents after each search for some time in case same search keyword comes in so you can skip expensive requests.